# Как задать расписание для работы алгоритма while True Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Есть алгоритм while True, который должен работать с понедельника по пятницу с 8 утра до 9 вечера, потом уходить в "спящий" режим на ночь и с утра следующего дня опять начинать работать. Пробую что-то с datetime, но не получается красивого решения.

```
Def schedule ():
   If текущее время == расписание:
      Return True
   If текущее время != расписание:
      Return False
```

Answer (score 2):

Понедельник это 0.

```
while True:
  do_something()
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  while now.weekday() > 4 or now.hour =< 8 or now.hour >= 21:
     time.sleep(60)
     now = datetime.datetime.now()
```